# android why is TabActivity with Activity's crashing when open Dialog

Tags: android, android-context

I see there are like 10 answers for this question and I have read them all
but cannot get this to work.

Im moving my activity's into this `TabGroup` and I have 3 activity's inside a tabgroup and got help doing it from here:  [Multiple Android Activities in a TabActivity](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)

When opening a Custom Dialog i get this error:

> 07-12 10:07:56.985: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9532): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@462d96f0 is not valid; is your activity running?

I know this error say that Context is bad.
On the `ColorPickerView` (below) that doesn't work, I'm debugging and can see the Constructor doing it's job but as soon as constructor finish it crashed.

The thing is I have 3 similar errors from the other two activities, one CheckBox, and two Spinner's.
I could easily fix it by changing the Context appropriately .

This on is more complicated and the View stack looks like this:

```
TabGroup  
.......TabHost (public class FileEditMainActivity extends Activity)    
...............ImageView (public class FileEditImageView extends ImageView )      
........................Dialog (public class ColorPickDialog extends Dialog )  
..............................View (private class ColorPickerView extends View  )
```

No matter how i change the Context the system tells my that the Context is not alive.
The `ColorPickerView` is always crashing..

Must say also that this is working if i dont use the `TabGroup`.
When I put the `FileEditMainActivit` in the TabGroup something goes wrong with the Context.
Anyone have an ide of what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since everything is inside an ActivityGroup i hade to do like

getparent().getParent()

This might look brutal but it worked and for my level of experience im consider it to be a victory :)

**EDIT**

the line `getparent().getParent()` would be the context parameter, eg:

`final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this.getParent().getParent(), null,  "Prcocessing", true, true);`

Comment: where you have putted this?
i have a normal alertdialog which make the same problem